# How does one reset Illustrator CS6 on Mac?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, mac

My Illustrator is acting a bit buggy; more precisely, no selection is actually visible. Selected text isn't highlighted, looking for an anchor is like looking for a needle in a haystack, and finding a handle is a futile effort from the beginning. My thinking is that this could be resolved by resetting Illustrator's preferences; where some blogs and fora suggest that it's under Home `Folder > Libraries > Application Support > Adobe > Adobe Illustrator CS6`, I haven't found the preferences folder in that directory. Is there any other way to reset it, or fix the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> on launch.
You won't get any dialog or any visible sign prefs have been reset, but they have. The logic is, the AI team felt if you hold those keys down on launch, you know what you are doing and therefore didn't provide any direct feedback.

If you want to manually delete the prefs, you've got the wrong location. You need:
`[home folder]/Library/Preferences/Adobe Illustrator CS6/`

Depending upon what OS you are running, that Library folder may not be visible. So, choose `Go > Go To Folder...` from the Finder Menu. Type in `~/Library` (that's tilde, forward-slash, Library) and the Library folder should open.

Comment: I've tried both methods; unfortunately, the problem persists. Is a complete reinstall of Illustrator necessary?

Comment: +1 just for your entertaining explanation of Adobe's tortured logic.

Comment: just want to say thanks... I had a problem where my Illustrator CS6 couldn't open (it would go straight to 99% cpu and 'not responding')... opening with `cmd`+`alt`+`shift` sorted it out

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've activated `hide edges` or `hide bounding box` -- I can never remember which term applies to which. Take a look in the `View` menu, the command will have changed to `Show ...`

Answer (score 0):

Commmand H for getting edges back

Answer (score 0):

`View > Show Edges`

Just had the same issue and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Find a thing that says essential it could say automation, or painting, its a set of default workspace settings, just reset essential and it should all be as good as new.