# How to reset Illustrator CS6 rectangle tool to zero degree?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, tools

I made previous work (as a beginner) in Illustrator CS6 and now when I select the rectangle tool it is by default oblique.

Also, I would like to reset the rectangle to its orginal alignement/direction (zero degree).

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: did you play with guides preferences?

Comment: I remember that I used the guides in a tutorial but not sure regarding its preferences.

Comment: reset prefs -http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11407/how-does-one-reset-illustrator-cs6-on-mac

Comment: There is no preference file in my folder I my folder C:\Users\<MyComputerName>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 Settings\en_GB\x86.In fact it seems that I was in the 'Essentials' workspace and for an unknown reason the rectangle tool provides oblique shape there. Everything becomes normal when I change the workspace.

Comment: Is it normal that the rectangle tool shape be oblique in the 'Essentials' workspace?

Comment: Go to Edit -> Preferences -> general and check that the Constrain angle is 0

Answer (score 1):

`Preferences > General` and set the **Constrain Angle** to 0°

Answer (score 1):

## How to change the angle of a vector shape

**If you need to only change the angle of a shape without changing your preferences, you can:**

**1)** Click the shape and then look on the option menu for the link with the word "Shape"

[image: Changing the shape of a rectangle or vector in Adobe Illustrator]

**2)** Change the angle and your other options there

[image: How to modify the angle or rotation of a rectangle or vector]

---

## How to change the default angle for all new vector shapes

**If you want to change the default angle and make every new rectangle with the same specific angle,** you can go in the "Preferences panel", and simply enter the angle you want by default in the "Constrain Angle" field.

[image: How to change the angle by default in Adobe Illustrator Preference panels]

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me. I had switched perspective grid that I did not notice. It can also be turned on you. You shut down as follows: View - Perspective grid - Hide Grid

Answer (score -1):

View - Perspective grid - Hide Grid worked for me